# I want to retrive a value only one time when clicking on a button many times and passing that value in form action tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form and in that form action I'm passing the particular country name to show the relevant details of that country when user is clicking on button.  When the user clicks on the button more than one time I get the url link for that many times.

Something like this:

```
www.staypleasure.com/chennaichennaichennaichennai
```

I want the country name only once even the user clicks on the button many times.

Like this:

```
www.staypleasure.com/chennai
```

Code:

```
$('#PropertyDisplayForm, #PropertyViewForm').submit(function(){ 
if($('#PropertyQ').val()==''){
   if($('#name').val()!=''){
      var str = $('#name').val();
      var location = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
      $('#PropertyQ').val(location);
   } else {
      var str = $('#PropertySiteCity').val();
      var location = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
      $('#PropertyQ').val(location);
   }
}   
var url_location = $('#PropertyQ').val();
var form_action = $(this).attr('action');
$(this).attr('action',form_action+url_location);
form_url = $(this).attr('action');
var property_url = '';
var property_type ='';
$.each( $( ".house-left .input.select .checkbox a.checked" ), function() {
   property_type = $(this).next('label').html();
   property_url = property_type.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();     
   });
   if(property_url!=''){
      property_url = '-'+property_url;
   }
   $(this).attr('action',form_url+property_url);
});
```

Can anyone help me to correct this issue with jQuery?

Comment: You are probably appending the country name to the current URL instead of "/". Need moar code.

Comment: Can you post your code?  Right now it's nearly impossible to help since we don't know all the things you are doing.

Comment: yeah.. I will post it..

Comment: I am not appending "/".. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/), the event handler function will only run once.

```
$("#button").one("click", function() {
  //your code
});
```

Comment: The browser is going to a new URL so (unless pushState is involved and there is no indication that that is the case) the page will reload and any DOM changes from JS will be lost, so this won't work.

Comment: Glad I'm helped. But don't understand why the downvote

Comment: Thanks.. I didnt put down vote.. someone else did it.. Actually I don't have enough reputation to vote for you..

Answer (score 0):

Once the button is clicked, you can pass the country value and then disable the button like this:

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() { 
// Code to pass the country value
$( "#button" ).attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

Comment: The browser is going to a new URL so (unless pushState is involved and there is no indication that that is the case) the page will reload and any DOM changes from JS will be lost, so this won't work.

Comment: @Quentin i read the question carefully and i cant find the relevant part where this is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the css porperty `pointer-events`.

```
$(".element").click(function() { 
    $(".element").css('pointer-events','none'); 
});
```

Comment: The browser is going to a new URL so (unless pushState is involved and there is no indication that that is the case) the page will reload and any DOM changes from JS will be lost, so this won't work.

Comment: If i use css property none then my button won't be clickable.. button should be clickable but wants to retrieve value only once..